# Fetch value based on Filter values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax

I am working on an Excel file where This is my First Table.

[image]

Now I have another table that has exactly the same Column names

[image]

Now What I wanted is When the Value of `Table1[Status]` is `Active` or `Pending` it should fetch all the values in `Table 2`. and Don't do anything when the `Status` value is `Pending` or `Empty`

The Expected Output

[image]

I have tried the following query but I think I am doing it wrong.

```
=XLOOKUP([@GID];Table1[GID];SWITCH([@[Status]];"Active";Table1[Status];"Pending"))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

A formula based solution cannot display the output in a **Table**.

Suppose your first table is called **Tbl_Source**, enter the following formula (in Excel 365) in a single cell and you will get the desired output:

```
=FILTER(Tbl_Source,(Tbl_Source[Status]="Active")+(Tbl_Source[Status]="Pending"))
```

[image: formula based solution]

---

**Solution 2**

If you want to show the filtered output in a new **Table**, you can try using the Power Query function which is built into Excel 2013 and all later versions.

Firstly, highlight any cell within the first table, then load the table to the Power Query editor:

[image: PQ Step1]

Secondly, click the filter button on top of the **Status** column, and select the desired criteria as you would normally do in Excel:

[image: PQ Step2]

Lastly, Close and load the output table. By default, Excel will load the output to a new table on a new worksheet. You can cut and paste the output table to the desired worksheet, or Google how to load the output to a query and then choose where exactly to load the output to.

If you want to add additional data or make changes to the first table, you need to right-click any cell within the output table and choose **Refresh**, then the output table will be updated with additional data.

[image: PQ Step 3]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

First

[image: First]

Then (Choose Table)

[image: Then]

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE(
Table1, 
Table1[Status] ="Active" || Table1[Status] = "Pending"
)
```